# Azure Frontend door shows "Our services aren't available right now " with service fabric cluster

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-front-door

I have set up an Azure Frontdoor in azure portal. I've created

2 frontend host

1. myappdev1.azurefd.net
2. dev1.myapp.com

Baackendpool with the following

1.BackendHostName= myappdev1.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
 2.Backendhostheader= dev1.myapp.com 
 3. HTTPS port 62652

and the Routing rule

with a https routing rule mapping both frontend to backend with HTTPS only.
myappdev1.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com is a service fabric cluster with a web application deployed on port 62652 so the url https://myappdev1.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:62652 works.

I've also mapped dev1.myapp.com to myappdev1.azurefd.net in a CDN

But on running either  https://myappdev1.azurefd.net or https://dev1.myapp.com

i get an error

> Our services aren't available right now
>   We're working to restore all services as soon as possible. Please check back soon.

Comment: What does you mean `I've also mapped dev1.myapp.com to myappdev1.azurefd.net in a CDN`?

Comment: I've used a CDN like cloudfare where the url dev1.myapp.com redirects to myappdev1.azurefd.net

Comment: If you temporarily remove the CDN redirect, how is the thing going? Why are you using azure front door?

Comment: to map names like  dev1.mayapp.com,  test.myapp.com, dev1cms.myapp.com etc to respective applications configured on clusters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is having a dns to the fabric cluster. Heres a use case
A website deployed on Service fabric. The URL for the website is www.devopsguru.com

Here are the steps

```
1. you have a domain :  devopsguru.com 
2. You have a AzureFrontdoor named : devopsguru.azurefd.net
3. you have a cluster named: myservicefabric.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com.
4. Create a record set :myservicefabric.devopsguru.com and www.devopsguru.com 
5. Map myservicefabric.devopsguru.com to myservicefabric.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com 
6. Map www.devopsguru.com to devopsguru.azurefd.net
7. Create a FrontendHosts for www.devopsguru.com
8. Create BackendPool called frontedbackendpool. 
9. Add Backends hosts with myservicefabric.devopsguru.com as Custom Host
10. Create Routing rules called frontendrules. In FrontendHosts select www.devopsguru.com  and backendpool select frontedbackendpool
```

That should do it

Comment: Can you explain your solution a bit more? I'm also trying to use front door and service fabric together, but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: I've update the answer with the steps . hope it helps

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you! Would also need to expose port(s) from the SF load balancer to allow traffic in from front door?

Comment: Yes. service fabric needs ports explicitly declared.

Comment: Perfect explaination! Thanks @ArshadBadarKhan